# Unable to launch ec2 instance "Launch Failed"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud, fortigate

I'm trying to launch a FortiGate c5.xlarge instance from the AWS marketplace. I keep getting the following.

```
Launch Failed

{
    "clientToken": "164876650066515092",
    "awsAccountId": "008420932876",
    "agreementId": null,
    "agreementRequired": true,
    "autoRoleCreationRequired": false,
    "instanceActionName": "RunInstances",
    "errorCode": "NeedsEntitlementCheck_InvalidParameterException",
    "errorMessage": "A non-retryable exception was thrown because of an invalid input for product e5126f4a-0d69-479f-919c-d5e158bd4d12, region us-east-1, amiId ami-065f5f3d485c1ec3f",
    "workflowStatus": "LAUNCH_FAILED",
    "productId": "e5936f4a-0d69-479f-919c-d5e158bd4d12",
    "isWorkflowExecutionFailed": false,
    "describeAgreementStepResult": null,
    "entitlementStatus": {
        "hasEntitlementCreatedInIAD": null,
        "hasExistingRegionalEntitlement": null,
        "hasNewEntitlementPropagated": null
    },
    "workflowStartTime": null
}
```

I went through this article and it doesn't seem to be any of the following messages.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-launch-issue/

Also checked that c5.xlarge is supported in us-east-1. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Sadly your question lacks details. You have to provide all information on how exactly you are launching the instance. It's parameters, region, Ami, etc.

Comment: <b> Hi Marcin <br/>

Here are the details  

AMI: Fortinet FortiGate (BYOL) Next-Generation Firewall
Instance: c5.xlarge
Network: Generic one I made with a internet gateway. CIDR is 10.9.0.0/16
Subnet: 10.9.0.0/24 in us-east-1a
eth0: 10.9.0.4
Everything else default

Let me know if you need anything else or if you have some commands that can narrow down the issue?

Comment: Is this a (very) new AWS Account? Where did the AMI come from -- Quick Start, Marketplace, Community or your own Account?

Comment: I hope you have brought the subscription before trying to launch this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up solving it by using the AWS CLI commands.

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-065f5f3d485c1ec3f --count 1 --instance-type c5.xlarge --key-name fortigate-aws --security-group-ids sg-019b89b5dd233cdae --subnet-id subnet-0457dda8b55b5bb10 --private-ip-address 10.9.0.4
```

Worked like a charm. Not sure why it didn't work through the marketplace.